# Recoding Numeric Vector R

Tags: r

I have a numeric vector, let's say something like:

```
x <- rep(1:6, 300)
```

What I would like to do is recode the vector, in place such that 6=1,5=2,4=3,3=4,2=5,1=6. I don't want to create a factor out of it.

Everything I have tried so far gives me the wrong counts because of the order, ie:

```
x[x == 6] <- 1 
x[x == 5] <- 2 ## Lines that follow where x[x == 2] removes 5's entirely from counts.
```

Note: I'm aware of the car package, but would prefer to use base R for this problem.

Comment: I guess I could create a new column and do something like abs(7-x[1])

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Construct a map between the old and new values, and subset with the old,

```
(6:1)[x]
```

Comment: Fits for more than just my particular usage case.

Answer (score 5):

Wouldn't something as simple as `7 - x` give you what you are after?

Comment: Sometimes, I figure these things out just from writing my problem out for someone else to answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

See manual for `car::recode`. Otherwise, create variable `y`:

```
y <- numeric()
length(y) <- length(x)
y[x == 6] <- 1
y[x == 5] <- 2
## ad nauseam...
```

It's always considered a bad practice to recode variables in place, because if you mess things up, you're probably going to lose data. Be careful.

Answer (score 4):

In your case, yes, just subtract.  In general, `match` can be quite useful in cases like this.  For example, suppose you wanted to recode the values in this `x` column to the values in the `y` column

```
> d <- data.frame(x=c(1,3,4,5 ,6),y=c(3,4,2.2,1,4.6))
> print(d, row.names=FALSE)
 x   y
 1 3.0
 3 4.0
 4 2.2
 5 1.0
 6 4.6
```

Then this would recode the values in `a` to the new values.

```
> a <- c(3,4,6,1,5)
> d$y[match(a,d$x)]
[1] 4.0 2.2 4.6 3.0 1.0
```

Comment: `match` only returns the first match though, so this only works if there are no repeated values.

Comment: But if there are repeated values, how would we choose which of them to recode to?

Comment: Actually, this is another problem that I'm facing. Now that I've got this part sorted.

Answer (score 1):

`rev(x)` ...  at least when the length is an even multiple of the sequence.

Comment: `> all( rev(x) == (7-x) )  #[1] TRUE`

Comment: that is simply an artifact of the generated data here. Consider data that isn't ordered as nicely: `x <- c(1,1,2,3,4,5,6,1); all(rev(x) == (7 - x))`

Comment: @Chase: Which _was_ what I said when I posted it. It's only a solution "when the length is an even multiple of the sequence".

Answer (score 0):

if you want to recode multiple variables you might take the following approach:

```
MapFunc = function(x) { 
    y = NULL;
        if (x %in% c("1","2","3")) {y=100}
        if (x %in% c("0","4")) {y=200}
        if (x %in% c("5")) {y=100}
    print(y)
    }
    MapFunc(x=1); MapFunc(x=0);   #working ok for scalars
```

#

```
X = matrix( sample(0:5,25,replace=TRUE), nrow=5,ncol=5)
apply(X,c(1,2),MapFunc) #working ok for matrices...
```