# In R, how do I map numeric values to factors, including Inf and NaN?

Tags: r

Using R, I have a vector such as

```
a <- c(0.1,0.6,23,Inf,NaN)
```

I would like to convert it to something like

```
c("Finite","Finite","Finite","Inf","NaN")
```

with as little pain as possible.  How is this done?

Thanks!
Uri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another method can be something like this (similarly to question [Recoding Numeric Vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858511/recoding-numeric-vector-r)):

```
type <- rep("Finite", length(a))
type[is.nan(a)] <- "NaN"
type[is.infinite(a)] <- "Infinite"
```

Comment: It's good practise to answer your own questions on SO, but this is a particularly poor example of an answer, since your solution introduces a bunch of new variables that don't appear in the question.

Comment: @UriLaserson I clean up a little your answer (covering Andrie's hints), feel free to rollback if you don't like it.

Answer (score 6):

`ifelse()` seems to work reasonably well:

```
b <- ifelse(is.finite(a), "Finite", ifelse(is.infinite(a), "Infinite", "NaN"))
> b
[1] "Finite"   "Finite"   "Finite"   "Infinite" "NaN"
```

Technically, that returns a character vector, which can be converted with `as.factor()` or just wrap `factor()` around the initial call to return a factor to begin with...though character may suit your needs depending on what you need to do.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `match` (and don't forget about `NA`'s):

```
f <- function(x) {
    codes <- c("NaN", "Inf", "Inf", "NA", "Finite")
    codes[match(x, c(NaN, Inf, -Inf, NA), nomatch=5L)]
}

f(a)
# [1] "Finite" "Finite" "Finite" "Inf"    "NaN"

f(c(7.777, -Inf, NA, Inf, NaN, 0/0))
# [1] "Finite" "Inf"    "NA"     "Inf"    "NaN"    "NaN"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a variant that uses R's own names except for "Finite" - so it's a bit shorter to write and as a bonus also handles negative infinity and `NA`:

```
# Include -Inf and NA...
a <- c(0.1,0.6,23,Inf,-Inf,NaN,NA)

format(ifelse(is.finite(a), "Finite", a), justify="none")
#[1] "Finite" "Finite" "Finite" "Inf"    "-Inf"   "NaN"    "NA"
```

...But if you really want the strings "Infinity" and "-Infinity", then this would do that:

```
sub("Inf", "Infinity", format(ifelse(is.finite(a), "Finite", a), justify="none"))
```

Finally, if you want to keep the `NA`s, then just don't call `format`:

```
sub("Inf", "Infinity", ifelse(is.finite(a), "Finite", a))
#[1] "Finite"    "Finite"    "Finite"    "Infinity"  "-Infinity" "NaN"       NA
```

Comment: Some variant could be `ifelse(is.finite(a), "Finite", as.character(a))` which transform `NA` to `NA` (not a `"NA"` string).

Comment: @Marek - yeah I know, but I thought I had too many variants already though :) ... And the last one maps Inf to Infinity as the OP requested.